# Need references for software architecture

Tags: c#, .net, sql, architecture

I have to develop an application which fulfills following demands:

1. It has to be developed in .NET (C#/Visual Studio/Standalone windows application).
2. The first important requirement is the visualization and manipulation of graph data. Here I will use ["ZedGraph"](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/samples.html) as I can tell for the moment.
3. The second requirement is a database connection. (SQL)
4. The database has to be accessible via the companies intranet.
5. Further some algorithmic functions have to be implemented in order to preprocess the given Graph-data before saving it to the database.

Certainly those are not all the requirements in detail but they briefly describe the main goals of the application.

Basicaly I could develop all the functions separately, drag & drop a GUI in Visual Studio's designer's, assign functionalities to the according GUI-elements etc.
But this somehow wouldn't feel right. Especially for the following reasons:

- I want to keep the application as **extensible** as possible.
- It also should be **maintainable**
- I could thing of many **more reasons** but that are the two which first come to my mind...

So my question is whether somebody can provide me with **references for software architecture** which would fit to this kind of project.
Especially **books** are important, as the application is a part of my thesis, so every method and decision has to be justified with a reference.

Thanks in advance,
BC++

Comment: Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture (almost illegal not to mention it): http://www.amazon.co.uk/Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321127420

Comment: An overview of the patterns are also available online: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft Application Architecture Guide

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16236

Answer (score 2):

[Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) by Martin Fowler.

Answer (score 1):

I would definately go for [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670), it is not related to any programming language in particular, instead it discusses good and practizes, totally recommended